# How do I transform a two-dimensional array into the ByteBuffer type required by FTLite?

Tags: mobile, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

In python, I got a applies to 113 * 113 array model, and it has been put into tflite, AnZhuoDuan I have got the 2 d array of 113 * 113, I want to know what I need to do to get the 2 d array to tflite model, I looked at the others write tflite run function of the model, using the bytebuffer data type, want to ask how to operate?
My two-dimensional array is a double, positive and negative

Answer (score 0):

I will first write how I transformed my bitmaps to bytebuffer and then I will show a workaround to your inputs

Function to transform bitmaps to bytebuffer:

```
private fun convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteBuffer {
    // Pre-process the input: convert a Bitmap instance to a ByteBuffer instance
    // containing the pixel values of all pixels in the input image.
    // We use ByteBuffer because it is faster than a Kotlin native float 
    multidimensional array.
    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(modelInputSize)
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

    val pixels = IntArray(inputImageWidth * inputImageHeight)
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)

    for (pixelValue in pixels) {
        val r = (pixelValue shr 16 and 0xFF)
        val g = (pixelValue shr 8 and 0xFF)
        val b = (pixelValue and 0xFF)

        // Normalize pixel value to [0..1].
        val normalizedPixelValue = (r + g + b) / 255.0F
        byteBuffer.putFloat(normalizedPixelValue)
    }

    return byteBuffer
}
```

where modelInputSize is:

```
modelInputSize = FLOAT_TYPE_SIZE * inputImageWidth *
            inputImageHeight * PIXEL_SIZE
```

//modelInputSize indicates how many bytes of memory we should allocate to store the input for our TensorFlow Lite model.

//FLOAT_TYPE_SIZE indicates how many bytes our input data type will require. We use float32, so it is 4 bytes.

//PIXEL_SIZE indicates how many color channels there are in each pixel. Our input image is a colored image, so we have 3 color channel.

//inputImageWidth and inputImageHeight are the width and height usually 224x224 that most pretrained models use.

So from above code if we want to transform the array to bytebuffer we have to use something like below:

```
private fun convertArrayToByteBuffer(twoDArray: FloatArray?): ByteBuffer {

    // We use ByteBuffer because it is faster than a Kotlin native float 
    multidimensional array.
    // FLOAT_TYPE_SIZE * WIDTH * HEIGHT
    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 113 * 113)
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

    if (twoDArray != null) {
        // Use [0] if this is 2D array or without [0] if it is one dimension array
        for (input in twoDArray[0]) {

            byteBuffer.putFloat(input)
        }
    }

    return byteBuffer
}
```

You should also check if your array is double or float and transform accordingly to apply to above code for FLOAT_TYPE_SIZE (in my example value for float is 4).

Check project [file](https://github.com/farmaker47/fs_korinthias/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/george/fs_korinthias/MainActivityViewModel.kt) with 2Darray of length 40

and project [file](https://github.com/farmaker47/face_verification/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/george/face_verification/camera/CameraFragmentViewModel.kt) with colored bitmap of 224*224 dimensions.

Good luck!